# PHP - get current time in specific time zone

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a comic, and have a database of comic pages with assigned dates.  I'd like to get the comic with the newest date, but not get comics for the future.

In other words, if `today` is 12-12-2000, and I have the following comics:

1. 12-01-2000
2. 12-12-2000
3. 12-30-2000

I will be able to query and get only comics 1 & 2.

So far, I've done this with the `gettimeofday()` function, just assigning it to a variable and doing a MySQL query.  Here's a simplified version of what I'm doing right now to get the LATEST (but not future) comic.

```
 $gtod1 = gettimeofday();
 $today = date("Y-m-d");
$directory = "comics";


$sql_lastcomic = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM comics WHERE story = ? AND `date` <= ? ORDER BY `date` DESC, id DESC LIMIT 1");
$sql_lastcomic->bind_param('ss', $directory, $today);
```

This works fine, except that I want it to always look at MY timezone, not the users time zone.  This way, the update is released at the same time for everyone.

I looked at the documentation for `gettimeofday()`, but wasn't sure how to modify it.  Or should I be modifying my MySQL statement?  Let's just say I want to use Mountain Time as my time zone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Karthik said, you can grab the timezone by using the DateTimezone object.

[Here's a link](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) to the docs.

Example:

```
$tz = 'America/New_York';
$tz_obj = new DateTimeZone($tz);
$today = new DateTime("now", $tz_obj);
$today_formatted = $today->format('Y-m-d');
$directory = "comics";

$query = "
SELECT *
FROM comics
WHERE story = ?
AND `date` <= ?
ORDER BY `date` DESC, id DESC 
LIMIT 1"

$prepped = $conn->prepare($query);
$prepped->bind_param('ss', $directory, $today_formatted);
```

Answer (score 5):

For America/New_York Time Zone

```
$today = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('America/New_York') );
echo $today->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 4):

For specific time zone select you can use [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) before using [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) or [time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function.

**Example:**

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka');
// Then call the date functions
echo $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

**OR**

Since PHP `5.2.0` you can do it using **OOP** and [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) as well (of course if you prefer OOP):

```
$now = new DateTime();
echo $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');    // MySQL datetime format
echo $now->getTimestamp();           // Unix Timestamp -- Since PHP 5.3
```

And to specify the `timezone`:

```
$now = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Dhaka'));
$now->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Dhaka'));    // Another way
echo $now->getTimezone();
```

For a time-zone reference, see [List of Supported Timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

## Some Useful Links

- [gmdate()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) - Format a
  GMT/UTC date/time
- [idate()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.idate.php) - Format a
  local time/date as integer
- [getdate()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php) - Get
  date/time information
- [getlastmod()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getlastmod.php) -
  Gets time of last page modification
- [mktime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) - Get Unix
  timestamp for a date
- [strftime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) - Format
  a local time/date according to locale settings
- [time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) - Return current
  Unix timestamp
- [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) -
  Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix
  timestamp
- [Predefined DateTime
  Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.types)

Comment: the first example in this answer is the easiest way to do it

Answer (score 1):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
//this will set your default timezone,for your use set default timezone as yours
$time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i'));

$date = date("d/m/Y g:i A", $time);
```

Hope this helps